Is there an automated way of creating a sync between a view in supabase and bigquery
I have a view in supabase and every month I need to refresh a table in bigquery with the latest data from this view in supabase. I have done it manually by exporting the data from supabase into a csv file and importing it into the table in bigquery. Looking to automate this now. Any suggestions please. There is big query wrapper but that is for reading from bigquery to Supabase.
